# getBlockSingletone in magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks

How we call `getBlockSingleton()` in magento 2

```
echo $this->getBlockSingleton('newmodule/newblock');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is exits at magento 2 also,but *you cannot use factory pattern* `newmodule/newblock` .Just need to you use `fullClass Name` of your block class.

*If you have tried at  phtml then try*

```
$block->getBlockSingleton({Full\Block\Class\Name\Here}::class);
```

**If block class:**

> $this->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton({Full\Block\Class\Name\Here}::class)

**Example:**

```
$this->getLayout()
            ->getBlockSingleton(\Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register::class)
```

### Call anywhere

First you need to inject  ***layout interface class and content  class*** if it `not available your  class`.

```
`Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface` 

`\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context`
```

at `_constuct` function

```
namespace {Vendorname}\{Module}\{RestOfPathOfclass};

class {ClassName} .....
{
    /**
     * Layout
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface
     */

     protected $_layout;

     public function __construct(
        .....
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout
        .......
     ) {
         $this->_layout = $layout;
         parent::__construct($context);
     }

    public function getMySingleTon() {

        $block =  $this->_layout->getBlockSingleton({Full\Block\Class\Name\Here}::class);
        $html = '';

        if($block){
            $html = $block->toHtml();      
        }      
        return $html;
     }

}
```